# What does @RC mean in SSDT SQL Server Unit Testing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssdt, visual-studio, unit-test

In Sql Server Unit Testing, SSDT, what does @RC stand for? Does it mean Row Count, or Row Column? Team wants to understand, we have been using it for long time, good tool which works, just curious.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@RC = Return code. The boilerplate unit test code will assign the stored procedure return code value to this variable, where it can later be used in a test case assertion.

Assuming there's a subsequent `SELECT @RC` after the proc execution in the unit test code, the `scalarValueCondition1` assertion in your screen image will verify the return code value is 1 in order for the test to succeed.